# HelpScreen overlay in React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working with help screens in React-native. My idea of help screen is something like this :

[image]

The workaround I tried is, I have created images from the screenshot and shown on the top of the actual screen whenever I need to show the help screen. I am wondering whether is this right way to do this ? or is there any other standard method available to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/mohebifar/react-native-copilot

Answer (score 0):

try this library, [react-native-app-tour](https://github.com/prscX/react-native-app-tour)